# SSIS executing .Net Console Job - relative paths

Tags: .net, xml, ssis

I have written a .net console application which uses an XML file to load a set of variables into the application.

During testing I have hard coded the absolute path of the .xml file using the UNC file path of where is stored on a shared drive. \\sharepath\config.xml

Now however, we wish to call the application.exe file from SSIS, which we can do absolutely fine is we continue using the hard coded path within the application, but when I change this to a relative path (config.xml) it fails as it can't find the config file.

Does anybody know why this wouldn't work? - I've read something about working directories for SSIS and wasn't sure if for some reason it is running the .exe file in a different location to that specified using the execute application task in the ssis package?

I'm basically trying to avoid having the file path hard coded into the application so that we can change it is the name of the file share changes in the future.

Thank you

Comment: In *all* applications you have to set the working directory. If you are in `C:\ ` and execute `c:\somefolder\myapp.exe` your working directory is `c:\ `, not `c:\somefolder`. Best option of course would be to pass the file's path as a parameter instead of hard-coding it. In any case, set the Working Directory of your application in the `Execute Task` step

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, thanks for your input you are correct that it was the working directory that the application was using as the relative path. When we put the config file in this folder it read it and worked as expected. - Cant accept your answer as it is in the comment space.

Answer (score 0):

I got bitten by this too.
The Working Directory is not where the dtsx file lives but rather where the DETEXEC.exec (or DTEXEC_Util.exe) lives.
This will be somewhere like 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn
I doubt you want to put your config to this location...
Your best bet is to set up an SSIS Configuration with the location of the XML file and then use this when loading your file (lots of examples out there...)

Comment: Thanks, we solved it by putting the config xml in a custom working folder defined in the execute process task. We didn't want to complicate it by passing variables to the application though.